# Regex in YAML file to be compared to hash value in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, yaml

So I'm trying to write a matcher to verify data from within a hash, pulling the definition from a YAML file. It's a little messy right now, but it'll get refactored later.

I want to verify a value is a digit within a hash. I'm able to parse the input files and YAML file.

Here's my YAML

```
:pmt_sum:
 - Type: NUMBER
 - Expected: !ruby/regexp '/\d*/'
```

Here's the code that's supposed to be doing the checking, it's part of a function that iterates through the hash (`header_def` is a hash):

```
header_def.each { |key, value|
    if parsed_hash[0][key] != value[2]["Expected"]
     puts "#{key} value does not match #{value[1]["Expected"]}, it returned #{parsed_hash[0][key]"
    else
     puts "working as intended"
    end
}
```

`hash[0][key]` would pull out the `:pmt_sum` key from the input file and output the message if it doesn't match what's in the YAML. This works for anything I hard code, however if I try to use regex, it spits out this:

```
pmt_sum value does not match (?-mix:\d*), it returned 7
```

Does anyone have tips on passing in regex to a Ruby program from a YAML file?

Edit: Disregard, I fixed it using a case statement to check the class of value[2]["Expected"], and used .match when it's a Regexp. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Instead of trying to store a Ruby regex in the YAML file, save it as a string, then use `/#{string}/` or `Regexp.new(string)` to convert it once the YAML has been read. That lets the YAML remain portable between other languages.

Comment: Without `header_def` it's difficult to tell where the problem is. Supply a minimal version of it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a case statement to check if the expected class is Regexp (and dumped things into variables for readability.)

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple things I'd do differently.

The YAML is going to generate an array of single element hashes, which isn't normal:

```
require 'yaml'

obj = YAML.load(<<EOT)
:pmt_sum:
 - Type: NUMBER
 - Expected: !ruby/regexp '/\d*/'
EOT

obj # => {:pmt_sum=>[{"Type"=>"NUMBER"}, {"Expected"=>/\d*/}]}
```

Instead, you probably really want a hash as it'd work as well. Here's a quick way to build one:

```
require 'yaml'

hash = {
  "Type" => "NUMBER",
  "Expected" => /\d*/
}

File.write('foo.yaml', hash.to_yaml)
```

Saving that and running will output "foo.yaml". Looking at that file shows the YAML to be:

```
---
Type: NUMBER
Expected: !ruby/regexp /\d*/
```

Reloading that using:

```
require 'yaml'
hash = YAML.load_file('foo.yaml')
hash # => {"Type"=>"NUMBER", "Expected"=>/\d*/}
```

At this point, the YAML is working correctly round-trip. If you *really* want your structure, build in Ruby first, then emit it to disk, then work on that:

```
require 'yaml'
hash = {:pmt_sum=>[{"Type"=>"NUMBER"}, {"Expected"=>/\d*/}]}
File.write('foo.yaml', hash.to_yaml)
```

Which, when run, creates 'foo.yaml' as:

```
---
:pmt_sum:
- Type: NUMBER
- Expected: !ruby/regexp /\d*/
```

But, back to why it'd be better to simplify the data. It's easier to access the entries with a simple hash:

```
hash = {
  :pmt_sum => [
    {"Type" => "NUMBER"},
    {"Expected" => /\d*/}
  ]
}

hash[:pmt_sum][1]['Expected'] # => /\d*/
```

versus:

```
hash = {
  "Type" => "NUMBER",
  "Expected" => /\d*/
}
hash['Expected'] # => /\d*/
```

About saving the regex into the YAML: YAML is supposed to be portable between languages, so you're locking it into Ruby, without any real major advantage gained. Instead of defining the pattern like:

```
Expected: !ruby/regexp '/\d*/'
```

use something like:

```
Expected: '\d*'
```

which will result in a string:

```
Expected: "\\d*"
```

in the YAML file.

Parsing that with YAML will return it back to a string, so convert it to a regex at some point before using it with something like one of these:

```
/#{ hash['Expected'] }/ # => /\d*/
```

or

```
Regexp.new(hash['Expected']) # => /\d*/
```

The resulting YAML will be used as needed by all languages, and you'll have the functionality you need.